# Are there non-isomorphic graphs with rationally orthogonal similar adjacency matrices?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, matrices

Let $A_G,A_H$ be the adjacency matrices of two non-isomorphic graphs.

Let $P$ be orthogonal matrix with rational entries.

> Is it possible $A_G = P^{-1}A_H P$?

[Paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002437959390239K)
gives algorithm for recognizing rational orthogonal similarity
which appears to involve computing the splitting field, which in
sage is quite slow.

> Is the algorithm in the paper polynomial?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are. The smallest pair are the subdivision graph of $K_{1,3}$ and $C_6$ with an isloated vertex. There are many more, look up "Godsil-McKay switching". 
The original source is at http://cs.anu.edu.au/~Brendan.McKay/papers/GodsilMcKayCospectral.pdf

It is not impossible that "most" pairs of cospectral graphs are rationally cospectral.

Comment: Thanks. What is reference for the explicit orthogonal matrix?

Comment: @joro: See Theorem 2.7 in the paper.